# File upload with ng-file-upload throwing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm using ng-file-upload for uploading  an image file. The code for html for the upload button is

```
<button ng-disabled="croppedDataUrl===''" class="button button-3d button-rounded" ng-click="vm.upload(croppedDataUrl)">Upload</button>
```

and the code for controller is as follows

```
vm.upload = function(dataUrl) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: AppConstants.api.images,
            data: {
                uploadedPicture: dataUrl,
                uploadedFrom: 'recipe'
            },
        }).then(function(response) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function(response) {
            if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function(evt) {
            $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        });
    }
```

When I click the upload button the following error is being thrown..

> undefined is not a function
>   at Upload.upload

I've inject the Upload service in controller 
and the sequence of the included js files are as follows

> angular.js
>
> ng-file-upload-shim.js
>
> ng-file-upload.js

So, I don't know where the problem is. Thanks in advance....

**Edit stacktrace**

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at vm.upload (http://localhost:8888/yn-site/app/dist/js/app.min.js:5000:24)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/yn-site/app/dist/js/vendor.min.js:13365:15), <anonymous>:4:379)
at callback (http://localhost:8888/yn-site/app/dist/js/vendor.min.js:23613:17)
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8888/yn-site/app/dist/js/vendor.min.js:16052:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8888/yn-site/app/dist/js/vendor.min.js:16152:25)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/yn-site/app/dist/js/vendor.min.js:23618:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.m.event.dispatch (http://localhost:8888/yn-site/js/jquery.js:2:40587)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (http://localhost:8888/yn-site/js/jquery.js:2:37297) vendor.min.js:12520(anonymous function) vendor.min.js:12520(anonymous function) vendor.min.js:9292Scope.$apply vendor.min.js:16157(anonymous function) vendor.min.js:23618m.event.dispatch jquery.js:2r.handle
```

Comment: Is that the actual error or your version of it? Post the stack trace.

Comment: The line at `app.min.js:5000:24`  points to the function Upload.upload({...})

Comment: show your module and controller declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you haven't properly initialized/ injected the dependencies.

In the module:

```
var app = angular.module('your_module', ['ngFileUpload']);
```

In the controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload) {
$scope.upload = function(dataUrl) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: AppConstants.api.images,
            data: {
                uploadedPicture: dataUrl,
                uploadedFrom: 'recipe'
            },
        }).then(function(response) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function(response) {
            if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function(evt) {
            $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go for vanilla js , this piece of code will work for any library or no library and compatible with ng-file-upload -

```
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.withCredentials = true;
          var formData = new FormData;
          formData.append('YOUR_FILE_OBJECT_NAME', file);
          xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
              console.log(this.responseText);
            }
          });

          xhr.open("POST", "YOUR_URL_HERE");
          xhr.send(formData);
```