# .upload is not a function in ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I am using [NG-FILE-UPLOAD](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) for file upload,preview and send to server.

I have added the files upload.js and upload.shim.js is my files direcory.added them in project and also added dependency in my angular module.working same as [this one](http://plnkr.co/edit/YjAp96TrEnLJcCQaFLLp?p=preview).

**Html:**

```
      <fieldset>
  <input type="file" ngf-select="" class="form-control" ng-model="picFile"
   name="file" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required="" />
  <img ngf-thumbnail="picFile" class="thumb" width="300"/>
  <button ng-click="picFile = null" ng-show="picFile">Remove</button>
  <br />
  <button ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
  <span class="progress" ng-show="picFile.progress >= 0">
    <div style="width:{{picFile.progress}}%" ng-bind="picFile.progress + '%'"></div>
  </span>
  <span ng-show="picFile.result">Upload Successful</span>
  <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
</fieldset>
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/student/studentimages',
            data: {
            uploadedPicture: file,
            uploadedFrom: 'recipe'
        },
    }).then(function(response) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.result = response.data;
        });
    }, function(response) {
        if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function(evt) {
        $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    });

}
```

But when i click submit it is giving me error as

```
Upload.upload is not a function
at Scope.e.uploadPic (app.min.js:1)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:13036), <anonymous>:4:296)
at update (upload.js:533)
at upload.js:611
at angular.js:17571
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5370)
at angular.js:5642
```

I have tried changing version too. What else can be tried to solve this?

Comment: Can you please post some code or provide a plunker that reproduce your issue?

Comment: i can't reproduce this by plunker as it is working well  there but not in my project.but yes i can provide code.Let me update question.

Comment: @user786 can you us the references and injecting code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't properly initialized/ injected the dependencies.

In the module:

```
var app = angular.module('your_module', ['ngFileUpload']);
```

In the controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload) {
$scope.upload = function(dataUrl) {
        Upload.upload({
            url: AppConstants.api.images,
            data: {
                uploadedPicture: dataUrl,
                uploadedFrom: 'recipe'
            },
        }).then(function(response) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.result = response.data;
            });
        }, function(response) {
            if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }, function(evt) {
            $scope.progress = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        });
    }
}
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194189/file-upload-with-ng-file-upload-throwing-error)

Comment: have visited this link already and added the dependency.Upload is dependency while probelm is Upload.upload function.

Comment: try adding                                             <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="POST" name="build_form"  >

Comment: but the whole form contain other type of data and it is submitted after steps too.ri8 now i am confined to one input field only.BTW how it is related to the prblm?

Comment: you can save all data using this api